# Pie chart not updating D3.JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I know this question has been asked many times but I am not able to solve the problem of updating my pie chart. I am completely lost. Could you please tell me what seems to the problem here ?

I tried the following way but the chart doesn't seem to update. I added a function change that is supposed to update the chart. I am updating the data, redrawing the arcs and changing the labels but it is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Load D3 -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="pie"></div>
    <script>
        var dataChart = { a: 9, b: 20, c: 30, d: 8, e: 12 };
        var dataChart2 = { f: 9, g: 20, h: 30, i: 8 };
        console.log(dataChart);

        var width = 300,
            height = 300,
            // Think back to 5th grade. Radius is 1/2 of the diameter. What is the limiting factor on the diameter? Width or height, whichever is smaller
            radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .range(["#2C93E8", "#838690", "#F56C4E"]);

        var pie = d3.pie()
            .value(function (d) { return d.value; });

        data = pie(d3.entries(dataChart));

        var arc = d3.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius - 10)
            .innerRadius(0);

        var labelArc = d3.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius - 40)
            .innerRadius(radius - 40);


        var svg = d3.select("#pie")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")"); // Moving the center point. 1/2 the width and 1/2 the height

        var g = svg.selectAll("arc")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");

        g.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.data.key); });


        g.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
            .text(function (d) { return d.data.key; })
            .style("fill", "#fff");

        function change(dataChart) {
            var pie = d3.pie()
                .value(function (d) { return d.value; });

            data = pie(d3.entries(dataChart));
            path = d3.select("#pie").selectAll("path").data(data); // Compute the new angles
            path.attr("d", arc); // redrawing the path
            d3.selectAll("text").data(data).attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; }); // recomputing the centroid and translating the text accordingly.
        }
       // calling the update functions
        change(dataChart);
        change (dataChart2);
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

[image: dataChart]

[image: dataChart2]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What are the values that you want the pie chart update to?

Comment: I have two data sets dataChart and dataChart2 , the pie chart needs to update whenever I call the change(dataset). But It is not doing it. Instead I just get one pie chart

Comment: You mean change from dataChart to dataChart2 object of values?

Comment: When the code runs, it loads the data from dataChart variable, so change(dataChart) won't change anything, but the change(dataChart2) changes the pie chart. Do you want to toggle the pie charts on each change() call?

Comment: Yes. So when I call the update function, the pie chart needs to update according to the data set passed as the parameter.

Comment: It already does that: https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/ExVVzXw?editors=0011

Comment: yeah but my change(dataChart2) is not updating the chart. I am not able to figure out why. The second chart should have labels as f,g,h and i but it still shows a,b,c,d,e

Comment: Try to refresh the codepen link. Look at the bottom of the code. There's a timer that changes the pie chart with the call to change(dataChart2). so the dataChart data is loaded initially and then after 3" the new data is loaded and displayed.

Comment: I pasted the pictures, I could see both having the same labels. I think there is some problem with the labelling for the second data